# Enabling same virtualenv settings in multiple ssh sessions

Tags: python, django, ssh, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

While running django, How should I enable or keep the same settings in all the ssh connections that I make?

I'm able to successfully run django in single ssh session but attempting to run django in a new ssh session causes/throws errors. After establishing a new ssh session I tried the following before running django

```
virtualenv djangorocks --distribute  
source djangorocks/bin/activate
```

Even after doing this I'm unable to run django syncdb & runserver commands.

Comment: cloud you please show the exact error..

Comment: I'm getting the error as indicated here http://dpaste.com/1526361/

Comment: have you tried to simply `import django` instead?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't run `virtualenv djangorocks --distribute` every time you connect with ssh, since it creates a **new** virtualenv. You need to navigate to the previously created one and activate it:

```
cd /path/to/existing/virtualenv
source bin/activate
python manage.py runserver
```

Comment: @mario23 You should edit your question to mention the error, then

Comment: goncalopp: Okay! I once again tried, but now I'm getting ImportError (from settings.py). But everything is working fine with the other terminal. Any ideas?

Comment: @mario23 please shouw us the exact output you're getting, and the commands you're entering